# Oracle database - use external Java

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, java-stored-procedures

I'm looking to find a way how to use higher versions of Java (1.6,1.7,...) instead of Java 1.4 which is available for Java stored procedures in a Oracle 10g.
I'm thinking about deploying a GlassFish server on the database server, and deploy web applications which functionalities would I use by calling them from PL/SQL.

Reasons for using Java instead of PL/SQL would be communications with various devices, calling and deploying web services, text processing...

Does anybody have a better, simpler idea on how to use higher version Java from PL/SQL in Oracle 10g database?

Comment: Might be [useful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741344/can-i-install-jdk-1-6-over-the-default-jdk-1-3-of-oracle-database)

Answer (score 1):

Forget about that. There used to be something called Jserver several years ago, but it was abandoned by Oracle. Theoretically you could use  Oracle ver 12c which uses JVM ver 1.6. But even this JVM is slightly different. For example it's GC can kill threads when they are not bound to a "live" DB connection. So you may encounter various interesting problems.

There is no way how to "upgrade" JVM inside current Oracle DB installation.

Comment: I'm aware that I can't upgrade the JDK inside the ORACLE DB. My question is, how to use, in a simple and effective way, an external JDK that is installed on the same machine as the DB. As I wrote before, I'm thinking about maybe using a Glassfish web server, and deploying web applications which would add functionality to my PL/SQL procedures. That is surely possible to do, but is that an effective way?

Comment: You can use RMI from Oracle Java stored procedures onto Glassfish.